# Spring security authentication and Ionic/Angular 1.X

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-security

**Some background :** I have an existing application built in Spring MVC and html5/css/jquery. It is currently secured by spring security. The login form POSTs to /j_spring_security_check.action with the username and password and the cookie/JSESSIONID gets automatically set in the browser.

**The issue :** We are building a (hybrid) mobile app using ionic/Angular.js and I'm having trouble with simple authentication. Is there any way to mimic the behaviour in Angular ?

I have tried the following piece of code without any luck - Spring security says the headers are invalid.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check.action',
    withCredentials:true,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: 'j_username=test@someemail.com&j_password=abc123',
})
.success(function(){})
.error(function(){});
```

It would be nice to be able to get spring security to recognize the user on each REST call so I would be able to use spring security annotations such as @Role etc...

Thanks !

Comment: can u share the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your code

```
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    static final String ORIGIN = "Origin";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getHeader(ORIGIN));
        System.out.println(request.getMethod());
        if (request.getHeader(ORIGIN) == null) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");// * or
                                                                    // origin as
                                                                    // u prefer
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        } else {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader(ORIGIN));// * or
            // origin as
            // u prefer
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        }
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            try {
                response.getWriter().print("OK");
                response.getWriter().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

also  you should to add in your xml web security file

```
<beans:bean id="CorsFilter" class="com.yourpackagetoyourclass.CorsFilter" />
    <custom-filter ref="CorsFilter" after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
```